# Probability of selecting a specific card from a split deck

Tags: probability

Say I have has only 4 Aces and 4 Kings. Probability of drawing an ace from those 8 cards is 1/2. Now if I split the 8 cards into two stacks randomly and then draw a card from one of the stacks, what is the probability that it will be an Ace ?

Comment: It would literally be exactly the same...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the left stack has $a$ aces and $k$ kings. Then $a+k=4$ and the right stack has $4-a$ aces and $4-k$ kings.

The probability of choosing an ace is, by the law of total probability:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \Pr\left(\text{Ace}\right) &=& \Pr\left(\text{left stack}\right) \cdot \Pr\left(\text{Ace} \mid \text{left stack} \right) \\ && \phantom{aaaa}+ \Pr\left(\text{right stack}\right) \cdot  \Pr\left(\text{Ace} \mid \text{right stack} \right) \\ &=& \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{a}{4} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4-a}{4} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and the result is irrespective of the splitting. Hence averaging over possible compositions of stacks still yields the probability of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to compute. The probability remains $\dfrac12$.

This is because of the fact that **cards have no preference for positions**,
so if we imagine all the 8 shuffled cards laid out in a line, an ace is equally likely to occupy any position.

Comment: They have no preference, period.